# How to change outline of Text Field in material.io?

Tags: android, textfield, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I have two text fields (Material.io) and when I tap on the first one, the outline colour changes to the colour I specified in `app:boxStrokeColor="@color/button_colour"` but when I choose the other text field the colour of the first text field changes to a shade of grey. How do I change this colour to any other colour?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a color, use a **selector**

```
app:boxStrokeColor="@color/myselector"
```

where the selector is something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Otherwise you can:

- use the standard selector for the `boxStrokeColor` and override the colors using `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay_til"`

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay_til">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

- use a custom style for your `TextInputLayout` to override the colors:

```
  <style name="Custom_OutlinedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyMaterialThemeOverlay</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyMaterialThemeOverlay" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```